# Inject place holder values at Spring boot application.yml file using intellij at run time

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, placeholder, application.properties

I am using Intellj to run my Spring Boot application which has application.yml file with place holder. The values of placeholder should be injected at run time depending upon the environment configuration.

```
server:
  port: ${SERVER_PORT}
```

I am trying to run the Spring Boot application from Intellij by passing the place holder value in the Environment Variable section of application run

I am getting below error while running this application:

Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Could not resolve placeholder 'SERVER_PORT' in value "${SERVER_PORT}"**
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Could not resolve placeholder 'SERVER_PORT' in value "${SERVER_PORT}"**

Answer (score 2):

Could be this is because your variable assignment is recursive, in a way. `SERVER_PORT` is the same property as `server.port` or

```
server:
  port:
```

See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config) for a list of sources for configuration properties and their order of precedence.

Try removing the section from your yaml file. If you declare an environment variable server.port or SERVER_PORT then SpringBoot will pick it up and use it.